# Wordpress how to get posts from category from advanced custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i want to use ajax from my wordpress and get informations:

First, which i can get is from'mark' category and field 'logo' from this category. (it works)

Second is to get other acf but not from category, but from post which has 'offer' custom post type  and i don't know how to get it

My code:

```
$mark = $_GET['mark'];
$categories = $_GET['category'];
$output = '';


$myquery['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'offer_category',
        'terms' => array($category,
        'field' => 'slug',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'mark_offer',
        'terms' => array($mark),
        'field' => 'slug',
    ),
);
$post = query_posts($myquery);


   $query = new WP_Query( $myquery ); 
   $ind=0; 
   $last = $query->post_count;
              if ( $query->have_posts()) { while ( $query->have_posts()) { $query->the_post();

                $ind++;


                $post_fields = get_fields();
                  // echo get_the_title();


                $myMark = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'mark_offer'); 

                $markId = $myMark[0]->term_id;

                $markLogo = get_field('logo', 'term_'.$markId );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using custom post type, you need do something like this:

```
     query_posts( [
         'post_type' => 'YOURTYPE', 'meta_key' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD', 'meta_value' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_VALUE'
     ] );
```